# Совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов

Tags: глаголы

Здравствуйте.

Объясните, пожалуйста: "Когда мы хотим сказать о том, сколько времени продолжалось действие, мы всегда используем глаголы несовершенного вида и специальные слова, которые указывают нам на продолжительность действия: долго, недолго, пять минут, целый год и т.д.»

Тогда как понять: «Я учился N,ском университете. Защитил диплом два года назад. Потом  ПОЕХАЛ на год в город X, где поступил на курсы». «Поехал на год» – СВ. «Ездил/уезжал на год» не звучит в этом случае. Но «Я ездил  в Петербург/был в Петербурге четыре года назад, там я 3 недели посещал курсы» Здесь НСВ в соответствии с правилом.
Очень нужно объяснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос хороший, но не сложный. 
Все достаточно просто. В вашем утверждении "Когда мы хотим сказать о том, сколько времени продолжалось действие, мы всегда используем глаголы несовершенного вида" слово "всегда" лишнее. )))
Есть случаи, пусть и нечастые, когда лексическое значение не соответствует грамматическому. Здесь смысл "поехал" при "на год" не в одноразовом действии (поездке) а в распространении *результата* действия на какой-то период.

Вообще некоторые т.н. глаголы движения (идти, плыть, лететь и т.д.) в СВ часто используется в такой роли, но не только они: *"поставьте кастрюльку на медленный огонь на пол часа", "взял почитать журнал на один день", "одолжил денег до зарплаты"* - и проч. Глаголы НСВ здесь действительно не всегда приемлемы (хотя иногда и они уместны), поскольку действие формально закончено: уже "взял", "одолжил" или должно быть закончено: "поставьте". А вот результат такого действия распространен по времени.

Эта форма в чем-то компенсирует давно утерянный в русском (и широко используемый, например, в английском) перфект. Конкретно - т.н. перфект результата. Но эта конструкция в русском очень ограничена в применении. Без указания конкретного срока (или "навсегда") её использование невозможно просто за отсутствием необходимости: глаголы СВ сами по себе успешно передают все смысловые оттенки завершенности, не связанные со временной протяженностью.

Answer (score 1):

Глаголы "ездить" и "поехать" различаются по смыслу: поехать  – начать действие, ездить = ехать, но обозначает действие повторяющееся, совершающееся в разное время, в разных направлениях, а также взад и вперёд.

В первом варианте перечисляется последовательность действий, которая заканчивается поступлением на курсы (поехал, поступил). Глагол "ездить" использовать нельзя, так как он предполагает возвращение обратно.

Если во втором варианте использовать глагол «поехал», то последовательность действий будет нарушена: только поехал в город, но не приехал (в этом случае глагол "поехал" нужно   закрыть каким-нибудь глаголом СВ). Поэтому вместо "поехал" используется глагол  «ездил» (ездил, посещал, потом вернулся обратно). Именно возвращением обратно заканчивается история.

Еще раз объясняю

Потом ПОЕХАЛ на год в город X, где поступил на курсы». Нельзя сказать: Потом ЕЗДИЛ на год в город X, где поступил на курсы». А почему нельзя? Потому что ездил - это значит съездил и вернулся, в то время как он в действительности поступил на курсы. Или надо сказать: Потом ЕЗДИЛ на год в город X, где учился на курсах».

Comment: София, сдается мне, что вы не совсем поняли вопрос. 
Он не о различии смысла парных вариантов глаголов движения, а об использовании совершенного вида вместо несовершенного при протяженном (как полагает автор) действии. Хотя на самом деле такое действие не является протяженным - см. мой ответ.  
"Последовательность" тут не причем. "Уехал на год" и "уезжал на год" - семантически идентичные конструкции (с точностью до стилистики). Обе не предполагают свершившегося факта возвращения: 
 "Уехал(уезжал) на год, а уже пять лет там" или "...а пробыл всего неделю".

Comment: Если бы не парный вариант глаголов поехать - ездить, то и вопроса бы не возникло. Обычно к теории обращаются в том случае, когда неясности возникают на практике. Я как раз объясняю конкретный практический случай: когда и какой глагол можно использовать.

Comment: "Уехал на год" и "уезжал на год" - это не совсем одно и то же. Уехал на год, а что дальше -  неизвестно. Уезжал на год - и вернулся.

Comment: >Если бы не парный вариант глаголов поехать - ездить, то и вопроса бы не возникло  
Допустим, хотя спорно.  
  
>Я как раз объясняю конкретный практический случай: когда и какой глагол можно использовать.  
  
Значит неправильно объясняете. Ну нет тут такого смысла, что обязательно "вернулся", я ж написал: "уехал" и до сих пор там. А про "последовательность" - это вообще вне моего понимания.

Answer (score 0):

Какого бы вида ни был в этой фразе глагол, обозначенная длительность относится не к его действию. Вполне нормальная фраза "Поехал на год" означает, что человек отправился в чужой город с намерением пробыть там год, и этот год относится к подразумеваемому "быть (в другом городе)" (или "учиться", как ясно из дальнейшего). Поэтому не нужно исследовать совершенные и несовершенные формы глагола "ехать". Точно так же, для носителя русского языка нормально "положить в банк денежки на год": год "лежать" они будут под действием глагола несовершенного вида, но "пролежат" этот год при другой форме глагола - так ли это важно?  Пусть этим озадачиваются люди, изучающие русский язык как иностранный (у них нет ориентиров, кроме худо-бедно выведенных из языка правил), да составители циркуляров (если какой-то фразе не судьба под какое-то их правило подпасть). Китайцы ведь перед тем, как что-то сказать, не задумываются, каким сочетанием тонов им нужно следующее слово произнести :) . Мы говорим правильно или неправильно совсем не потому, что пользуемся или не пользуемся классификацией частей речи.

Comment: Жаль, что Вы не поняли моего ответа, могу добавить следующее. 1. Не стоит носителю языка углубляться в теорию глаголов СВ и НСВ, так как он интуитивно владеет навыком их употребления. 2. Но стоит помнить вот о чём: если вы имеете дело с глаголами ездить, ходить и др. (они  обозначают действие повторяющееся, совершающееся в разное время, в разных направлениях, а также взад и вперёд), у Вас всегда будет ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ составить НЕКОРРЕКТНОЕ предложение. И не надо сравнивать пару "поехал - положил". Поехал - начало действия, когда от вас ждут продолжения сюжета. Положил - просто закончил действие.

Comment: Вот ваш пример: "Потом ПОЕХАЛ на год в город X, где поступил на курсы».Ездил/уезжал на год -  не звучит в этом случае". Вы получили для себя ответ, почему не звучит? Вот это и есть некорректное предложение.